# Cannot delete maven target folder in windows 8.1

Tags: windows, filesystems, maven

I have used IntelliJ's maven plugin to build my project with `mvn clean install`.
It fails on `clean` due to problems deleting certain folders within the target-directory.

I had this error multiple times and I could always solve it by utilizing unlocker or bash `rm -rf <dir>`, but not this time.

These are the things I tried to delete the folders:

1. windows explorer > right-click > delete:

   seems to do nothing, not even output an error
2. cygwin > bash rm -rf: rm:

   `cannot remove 'tiny_mce/plugins/fullscreen': File exists`

   `rm: cannot remove 'tiny_mce/plugins/iespell': Directory not empty`
3. unlocker > delete:

   [unlocker option selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/54vut.jpg)

   [error message: could not delete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O2AMx.jpg)
4. eclipse/intellij > delete

   Java IOException: cannot delete...

I hope there are other options since I cannot continue my work on my local machine as long as I have this problem. And I certainly do not want to switch my workspace and setup everything from the beginning under a new path. This can't be the solution!

**Update:**

5. Moving the folder to another location

   Strangely, it worked. I still cannot delete that folder, but I could continue my work. However, I want it removed...

Comment: Take a look: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/faq.html

Comment: thanks @duDE, I can successfully run the job by using  -Dmaven.clean.failOnError=false but the folder is not removed, thus being packed into the war-file

Comment: it also seems as if my filesystem got damaged or some sort of, since no tool ever can delete that folder. It can be moved but not deleted. I remember having had that issue years ago on Windows 98...

Answer (score 0):

The answer to my problem was to check my filesystem for damages and repair them.

So I ran `chkdsk.exe /x /f /r`, confirmed and restarted my system and voilà... I can finally delete that folder.